# Handle the data payload without user tapping on the notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

> When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.

Is there any way to handle the data payload without user tapping on the notification?

Comment: Be more specific about your use case. Like what will happen when app handles that data? How do you want to use that data? Because there might be a better way to do the same.

Comment: @NishantDubey I want to store the data in a SQLite

Comment: Are you using firebase as backened or just using fcm?

Comment: @NishantDubey only the cloud messaging portion is used as backened

Comment: If you are using FCM then below link will help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/39665485/4247543](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39665485/4247543)

Answer (score 1):

Basing from the FCM docs on [Handling Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages):

```
App state   Notification        Data                Both
Foreground  onMessageReceived   onMessageReceived   onMessageReceived
Background  System tray         onMessageReceived   Notification: system tray
                                                    Data: in extras of the intent.
```

It's not specifically handled ONLY by tapping on the Notification. You may handle it in the `onMessageReceived()`. Pretty sure the tap action also depends on how you implement it.

If you intend for it to do something else, do provide more details.

Comment: I want to store the data in SQLite

Comment: @MridulSKumar you can handle the data payload in the `onMessageReceived()`. Retrieve the details you need from their, then save it to the device SQLite using your usual implementation.

Comment: onMessageReceived() is not called when the app is in background. It works only when app is in foreground.

Comment: I see. When the app is in background (referring to the table above), the data payload can be retrieved ***Data: in extras of the intent.***

Comment: To get the data in extras of the intent I guess you have to click on the Notification. What if the user clears the notification without clicking it ?

Comment: I'm referring to the both column in the above table

Comment: @MridulSKumar If you are only using the data payload, then it should call `onMessageReceived()`. Unless you're using both notification and data in your payload, the behavior is as you would see in the table. Why the downvote?

Comment: @MridulSKumar I see. Anyways, as I mentioned in the last comment, do try to only use data payload and see if you are able to handle it via the `onMessageReceived()`.

Comment: In case of multiple notifications, *extras of the intent* will overwrite with the last notification arrived. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive data payload **when app is not running** then you need to use a custom app-server with **http protocol(in your case)** which will send only **data payload** *no notification* and will send data to fcm endpoint like this

```
    { "data": { "some_key" : "some_value",
 "some_more_key" : "some_more_value" }, 
"registration_ids": ["device-token","device-token2"] }
```

**or** just to send data from server to one client

```
{
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "Nick" : "Test",
     "body" : "Your message here",
     "Room" : "Some Test Room"
   },
 }
```

Then using **POST** you can send downstream message to your device and it will work the way you want. If you want to have a basic idea of such app server please consider this : [How to push notification to client when Firebase has a new entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670667/how-to-push-notification-to-client-when-firebase-has-a-new-entry)

I have posted **basic Java Servlet code** here and also a **node.js** code by firebase official blog.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm able to receive the data and store in SQLite when the app is in foreground. onMessageReceived() is not called when the app is in background. I'm sending data along with notification. So according to their docs when app is in background Notification is displayed in the system tray and data is handled in the extras of the intent.

Comment: @Nishant Dubey FCM Docs Clearly says that if App is in background onMessageReceived not called Please Read DOCS carefully

Comment: Hi Mohit. I do understand your concern . But downvoting the answer is not the way unless you check the **edit**

Comment: @MridulSKumar check updated answer. Its the only solution using fcm